# Xpages - Issue: 'context.getUser().getCommonName()' is null

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Has anyone else noticed this problem:

'context.getUser().getCommonName()' is null

I get this problem on one particular server, but can't reproduce this on other servers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is stack trace of the issue:

```
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:451)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.isRenderedProp(UIDataPanelBase.java:81)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.fillShadowedFlags(UIDataPanelBase.java:231)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.encodeBegin(UIDataPanelBase.java:240)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:840)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:641)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:335)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:248)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:200)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1267)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1251)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:598)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:421)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=1, col=35: 'context.getUser().getCommonName()' is null
    com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException.<init>(InterpretException.java:123)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTMember.interpret(ASTMember.java:97)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:88)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.binaryop.ASTBinaryDefaultOp.interpret(ASTBinaryDefaultOp.java:49)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:221)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:193)
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:451)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.isRenderedProp(UIDataPanelBase.java:81)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.fillShadowedFlags(UIDataPanelBase.java:231)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.encodeBegin(UIDataPanelBase.java:240)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:840)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:641)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:335)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:248)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:200)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1267)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1251)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:598)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:421)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this?

Comment: I think I found an alternative by using session.getEffectiveUserName() - I am trying to use it to get current user name and also check whether it's anonymous or not. I would still be interested in finding out why it doesn't work on an XPage used in multiple places including rendered property of a panel.

Comment: This is server specific! So not sure whether this is some sort of a config issue!

Comment: Can you go back and see what you get as context.getUser()? On my own system, when the user is not connected to the internet at all and running local, getUser returns (fullName: null, name: CN=David Navarre/O=DAI, mail: null, groups: null, roles: []). If I'm connected, I get all values as expected. It apparently has something to do with access to the directory to establish the getUser object properly.

Comment: thanks David, I will check and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this problem too, for users authenticated from a secondary domino address book (knonw thru directory assistance)
We decided to not use anymore "context.getUser()" :

- replace context.getUser().getRoles() by database.queryAccessRoles(session.getEffectiveUserName())
- replace context.getUser().getFullName() by userBean.commonName
- replace context.getUser().getCommonName() by userBean.commonName
- (and even if this one works) replace context.getUser().getDistinguishedName() by session.getEffectiveUserName()
- replace context.getUser().getGroups() by _getUserGroupNameList()
  (not by session.getUserGroupNameList(), list of NotesName instead of strings)

  ```
  function _getUserGroupNameList() {
      var lNotesName:java.util.Vector = session.getUserGroupNameList(); // list of NotesName
      var lString:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();
      for (var i = 0; i < lNotesName.size(); i++) lString.add(lNotesName.get(i).getCanonical());
      return lString;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I build a quick sample and cannot reproduce the error

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
    value="#{javascript:context.getUser().getCommonName()}" />
```

What are you doing exactly?

by the way, you could also use EL

```
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
    value="#{context.user.commonName}" />
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrich - this problem is server specific for some reason, because it doesn't happen on my server, but happens on the customer's server - it has me stumped! This is what I am doing on a panel: rendered="#{javascript: context.getUser().getCommonName().toLowerCase() != 'anonymous'}"

Comment: Thanks for the EL suggestion, I agree it's best to use EL where possible - better performance - although still not sure why something like this would happen on one server and not others! Maybe it's some sort of a weird config issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure why this is causing an error on one particular server and not others. I have decided to use session.getEffectiveUserName() in the mean-time to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have this problem. It's to do with user id and NAB on this server. I don't know what exactly but I've had a problem with id password digest. That means that my password in person document(names) on this perticular server was not synced with the psw on my ID. So in notes client I got "Sorry you're locked out" message. I've now refreshed the password and can login, but after that this started to happen. I can't get username. Neither from context, nor session. Basically it is working funny.